# while loop to prompt for valid number input

Tags: javascript

Please help me fix my code so as to perform input validation from my prompt.
I am a JavaScript beginner. I am trying to create a getWidth() and getLength() functions that would get input from a user. Later on the inputs would be used to calculate the area of a rectangle. It's a mini code just to validate the input the user is giving to these functions.
Here is my first approach:

```
const getWidth = function () {
 
 // check if the number passed for width is valid a number
  let width;
  width = parseFloat(prompt('Enter the width of your rectangle '));
  while (typeof width !== 'number' || width <= 0 || !isNaN(width)) {
    width = prompt('Enter a valid value');
  }

  return width;
};

let newWidth = getWidth();
console.log(newWidth);


/****Solution no 2 **/
const getWidth = function () {
 
  // check if the number passed for width is valid a number
  
   let width;
   do{
    width = parseFloat(prompt('Enter the width of your rectangle '));
    if(typeof width === 'number' && width <= 0 && !isNaN(width)){
      return width;
    }
   }while(typeof width==='string' || width <= 0 || !isNaN(width) )
   
   return width;
 };

 
 let newWidth = getWidth();
console.log(newWidth);
```

/*Solution 2 fails at while loop*/

Comment: You did not use parseFloat on the prompt in the while loop in Solution 1

Comment: It never exits the while loop in solution 2 because you check if the width is less than or equal to 0. You are also checking if the width is a number with `!isNaN` in the while condition.

Comment: there are 2 parts, the JS code part and the HTML interface part. With HTML5 the interfaces have evolved and make it possible to avoid having to always re-coding input controls. in your case you have to use a [input type range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range)

Answer (score 1):

Prompt the user for a number input, *while* their input is not a number.

For the prompt, we use yours:

```
width = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the width of your rectangle "));
```

For the other half, we use `Number.isNaN(Number(width))`.

This is just a simple and readable way to check if the input was a numeric string.

`Number` coerces its input to a number, or NaN if it's not possible, and we check if the result is NaN with `Number.isNaN`.

```js
const getWidth = function () {
  let width;
  
  do {
    width = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the width of your rectangle "));
  } while (Number.isNaN(Number(width)));

  return width;
};

console.log(getWidth());
```

References:

- [Number function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#function_syntax)
- [Using Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)